# Node.js Streams: When will _writev Be Invoked?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

The Node.js documentation makes the following comments about a Writable stream's `_writev` method.

> The `writable._writev()` method may be implemented in addition or alternatively to `writable._write()` in stream implementations that are capable of processing multiple chunks of data at once. If implemented and **if there is buffered data from previous writes**, `_writev()` will be called instead of `_write()`.

Emphasis mine.  In what scenarios can a Node.js writable stream have buffered data from previous writes?

Is the `_writev` method only called [after `uncorking`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_uncork) a corked stream that's had data written to it?  Or are there other scenarios where a stream can have buffered date from previous writes?  Bonus point if you can point to the place in the Node.js source code where it makes a decisions w/r/t to calling `_write` or `_writev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_writev()` will be called whenever there is more than one piece of data buffered from the stream and the function has been defined. Using `cork()` *could* cause more data to be buffered, but [so could slow processing](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28408).

The code that guards `_writev` [is in `lib/internal/streams/writable.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a4fce32eabf40e6a1a34f384999bf8660b59639a/lib/internal/streams/writable.js). There is a [buffer decision](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a4fce32eabf40e6a1a34f384999bf8660b59639a/lib/internal/streams/writable.js#L557-L579) and then [the guard for the write.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a4fce32eabf40e6a1a34f384999bf8660b59639a/lib/internal/streams/writable.js#L414-L419)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to force it by using `cork()` and then `uncorck()` which was very useful for testing it.